# How do I get the data the user inputs and insert it correctly?

Tags: php, sql

How do I get the data the user inputs (SUCID) and insert it correctly with SUCID, SID, CID

Comment: What is the problem? Simply dumping a bunch of code and saying "It doesn't work" isn't helping us help you. Be specific.

Comment: It gets up to the if/else statement.  I can enter the student's ID into the SUCID box, but then it never gets to the register-exec.php.  i want it to insert the CID, SID, and SUCID into my database, and its not doing that.

Comment: after hitting the REGISTER button, nothing happens is what i mean

Comment: Are you sure you have a database connection? Do the tables you've specified exist?

Comment: yes the table is called register and i am able to connect to db as well yes.

Comment: Is it called `register` or `registered`? Your code has `registered`

Comment: `$_POST[CID]` should be `{$_POST[CID]}` in `application2.php`. Does that solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$SUCID = clean($_POST['SUCID']);
```

I suppose your function clean() doesn't works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the

```
<button type='submit'>
```

to

```
<input type='submit'>
```